# Is it possible to show a different icon on taskbar for a Windows application instance ran with a different user account?

Tags: microsoft-edge, taskbar, coding-efficiency

I run 2 Microsoft Edge browser instances for work, 1 for normal use and the other for AWS Console SAML login. I often mix them up.
The latter is started with "runas /u: 'C:\ \msedge.exe'".

Is there a way to make them show different taskbar icon so that I won't mix them up?

https://www.reddit.com/r/edge/comments/jdq1u6/how_to_change_the_icon_for_edge_on_the_taskbar/ This way won't work, two instances both show new icon.

Comment: Hi Peter, may I know if my solution works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's an idea to set different icons for them, or rather, different badges. The only thing you'll need to do is give each instance a profile, and then you need to choose an avatar for it at **Settings --> Profiles --> Your profile --> More actions (···) --> Edit**. Now you can notice the difference between instances.